# MIP vs CP for scheduling problems

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, constraint-programming, mixed-integer-programming

It is known that exact mathematical strategies such MILP are not efficient for large instances of the flexible job shop problem. However, still, nowadays it is possible to find proposals of MILP formulations for the FJS problem. It may be due to the fact that it is interesting to use the MILP model for experiments involving non-exact methods as metaheuristics (GA, FA, TS, etc) since it provides lower bounds.

I also read that CP should be chosen when finding a feasible solution is more important than an optimal solution. Is that a true statement?

Comment: Given NP-completeness (and P != NP) there is no silver-bullet (solving it exactly). There will always be (big enough) instances which can't be solved in time, no matter the method. So every approach is somewhat a heuristic targeted at kind of instances. What method is best is hard to say in heuristic-world and needs experimentation. But in general, yes, CP is more of a feasibility-propagator while MIP is more an optimality-propagator. There are nice [courses](https://www.coursera.org/learn/discrete-optimization) by Van Hentenryck treating all three concepts (older ones at youtube i suppose).

Comment: Due the nature of the CP, a CP solver provide lower and upper bounds?

Comment: No. It does not. (But every found feasible solution is an upper-bound of course; in minimization)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I also read that CP should be chosen when finding a feasible solution is more important than an optimal solution. This is true?

I think that this statement is becoming less and less true with the recent progress of CP. Especially for scheduling problems. For instance you mention the flexible job-shop scheduling problem. On this problem, generic CP techniques were used to improve and close many of the open instances of the classical benchmarks (both by finding better solutions and by finding tighter lower bounds). See for instance [1]. In this article, the same CP techniques are used to improve/close many other classical scheduling problems (in particular several variants of job-shop and RCPSP).

And, yes, CP can provide some lower bounds. If you add the constraint “objective < K” and the search proves this problem is infeasible, then K is a lower bound. It is also to be noted that some modern CP solvers use linear relaxations to guide the search and provide some lower bounds.

You can also have a look at [2] for a comparison of the performance of several MIP models and a CP model for the massively studied job-shop scheduling problem.

And if you are interested in a more complete view of how different CP techniques can be integrated in a generic CP-based optimization engine, there is also this very recent article [3] (http://ibm.biz/Constraints2018).

[1] P. Vilim, P. Laborie, P. Shaw. “Failure-directed Search for Constraint-based Scheduling”. Proc. 12th International Conference on the Integration of AI and OR Techniques in Constraint Programming for Combinatorial Optimization Problems, CPAIOR 2015

[2] W-Y. Ku, C. Beck. “Mixed Integer Programming Models for Job Shop Scheduling: a Computational Analysis”. Computers & Operations Research. 2016.

[3] P. Laborie, J. Rogerie, P. Shaw, P. Vilim . “IBM ILOG CP Optimizer for Scheduling”. Constraints journal, 2018

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I will check all your references. I have one more question. I am working on an extended version of the FJSP. I defined my MILP models for the different variants of my problem. I am using the IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.7 solver. Could you talk a little more about the CPLEX CP Optimizer? Would be difficult for me to "remodel" my problem as CP?

Comment: If you want to take advantage of CP Optimizer, indeed, you will have to reformulate the problem using different concepts (like interval variables).  Article [3] I mentioned above can be a good entry point. Note also that there is a formulation of the (classical) flexible job-shop problem in CP Optimizer in your installation of CPLEX Optimization Studio (it is called sched_jobshopflex).

Comment: Thank you again. I am not using the CPLEX Optimization Studio, I am coding in C++. Anyway, that is a good entry point, I will check it.

Comment: In C++, the CP Optimizer flexible job-shop example will be in CPLEX_INSTALL_DIR/cpoptimizer/examples/src/sched_jobshopflex.cpp

Answer (score 2):

What you said is about right.

For some types of problems it is hard to construct an efficient MILP model to solve them, and they are better off being solved by metaheuristics. However, if a LP can be constructed in a way as to provide a tight and non-trivial bound to a problem then it would be possible to verify if the solution of a good metaheuristic reaches optimality or near-optimality. This means that you can (potentially) solve some instances of some types of NP problems to optimality using only linear programming and metaheuristics.

As for CP, it is very good at finding if a problem is feasible (or proving that it is infeasible). CP *can* be used to find optimal solutions, but it is not its strong suit and MILP usually does better in that regard.